# loading a lot of data into WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, bigdata

I have 4 sql queries that fetches a decent amount of data, where 2 of them take about 30 and 60 seconds respectively.

I intend to cache a lot of the data so after the initial load it won't take that long...

However the initial load will still take a lot of time so I'm just wondering **What's the best way to fetch and load these 4 datatables from SQL Server into 4 individual WPF datagrids?**

I don't think there is much to be gained performance-wise from the sql query itself. They are pretty straightforward selects but the bottleneck is a `JOIN` on a linked server on another network.

Is it simply a matter of asynchronously running each query and loading them, or is there a better approach?

Comment: How often is the app going to be loaded up/ by how many users? Would it be worth having something on the DB maintain a cache itself so you can get unbottlenecked data that may be a few minutes old?

Comment: @HighCore I guess you didn't read the question...

Comment: @CraigGraham As of now only about 10 people, but it may be loaded several times during the day, whenever it's needed (it's a small standalone app that simplifies a lot of things).

Comment: implement some sort of service(WCF, ASP.Net Web API, etc....) and cash data right there for some time.... Is that rocket science?

Comment: @user1021726 I don't see the code you already tried and which you're having problems with, that's why I'm asking

Comment: To further answer @CraigGraham's answer; the sql data will only update itself once every 24 hours so keeping an up-to 24 hour old cache should work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formalise it; your bottleneck is in the backend design and nothing to do with the frontend application. Change the backend design so your app no longer requires the join between servers each time an instance of the app starts up. This could be a simple executable running periodically on the database server and maintaining a cache table that your frontend retrieves in one hit, or it could be a full service that your app accesses the database through.

Further, since the data only updates every 24 hours- and is still probably a sizeable chunk to be shifting about- maintain a local cache on each end user machine that's only refreshed if it is older than the last central version of the data.

Comment: Others have given great answers but yours is the one that addresses the bottleneck with the database. A combination of keeping a cache table and asynchronously load the data into the UI would be the best way to go about it, maybe how Dean K suggested.

Answer (score 1):

In the get you could run query asynch
That is probably the most efficient approach

You many want to look at priority binding
[PriorityBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Another option is to use a BackgroundWorker to retrieve the DataTable in the backgound.
[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
As for 4 DataTables you have a few choices.
You can fire them all off at once.
Or you can fire the next in the complete event of the prior.

Answer (score 1):

Use Task Parallel Library when you call the method that fetches the data from the database and that operation will be performed on a separate thread created by the TPL...

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetLotsOfRecordsFromDB()).
            ContinueWith(t => ...);
```

Use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` in `ContinueWith` if you need to access the UI thread.

That is by far the simplest, least verbose way of doing it...

Comment: Nice, I'll give it a try.